# How Do I Delete A Target In Xcode 9?

Tags: xcode

Xcode 9 is quite similar to Xcode 8.

I'm building Apple's Open Source IOGraphicsFamily.

In the Products group there is a target called iogdiagnose.  Its source produced many compiler errors when I tried to build all my targets, so I removed the group with iogdiagnose's source from my project.

But the iogdiagnose target is still there.  It produces a link error - missing main.

Google failed to yield insight.  There was the same question for Xcode 6.1, but Xcode 9 is quite different from 6.1.

Building the IOGraphicsFamily driver stack has been a huge PITA.  I need my own build so I can enable the driver stack's kprintf logging.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Simply right-click on the target and click on Delete.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW that UI is hiding from us developers.  I accepted your answer.

Comment: You may have hidden it. If you don't see the pane with PROJECT and TARGETS, click that little blue square icon just above PROJECT in the screenshot.

Answer (score 7):

I deleted the target by editing the project.pbxproj that's in the .xcodeproj bundle.

That worked just fine however but there must a GUI to delete targets.

The great thing about Xcode is that Apple keeps us sharped-eyed by rearranging the GUI in profound ways with each new release.